# Using JSoup Extract Specific Table (TableHeaderValue -> TableBodyValue) Contents

Tags: java, jsoup

Good day,

I am using jsoup to extract data from a table

Table Content is

```
<table class="compare-products-table compare-products">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
            <p>GPSMAP</p>
            </th>
            <th>7x1</th>
            <th>8x0/10x0</th>
            <th>4000/5000</th>
            <th>6000/7000</th>
            <th>7400/7600</th>
            <th>8000/8500</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Radar Overlay</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dual Range</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>MARPA</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>True Color</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Auto Bird Gain</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Echo Trails</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Pulse Expansion <span class="kicker pri sm">NEW</span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dual Radar Support</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Programmable antenna parking</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
            <td class="checked">•</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output value should be like

```
7x1 -> Radar Overlay: yes
8x0/10x0 -> Radar Overlay: yes
4000/5000 -> Radar Overlay: yes
6000/7000 -> Radar Overlay: yes
7400/7600 -> Radar Overlay: yes
8000/8500 -> Radar Overlay: yes

7x1 -> Dual Range: no
8x0/10x0 -> Dual Range: no
4000/5000 -> Dual Range: yes
6000/7000 -> Dual Range: yes
7400/7600 -> Dual Range: yes
8000/8500 -> Dual Range: yes
```

etc

examples I've seen aren't too clear on how to get the contents if it has attribute of the table

what i get atm :

```
       Elements elementsFeatures = docProductsAttr.select("#featureTab"); // Feature
        if (!elementsFeatures.isEmpty()) {
            Elements selectThead = elementsFeatures.select(".compare-products thead tr th:gt(0)"); // get Table Head skipping 1st element
            List<String> collectTableHead = selectThead.stream().map(i -> i.text()).collect(toList()); // collect head text value to List
            Elements selectTbodyTr = elementsFeatures.select(".compare-products tbody tr"); // select Body tr to mix it with Head value
        }
```

Will be appreciated if someone provide me with the code required to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Elements elementsFeatures = docProductsAttr.select("#featureTab"); // Feature
if (!elementsFeatures.isEmpty()) {
    for (Element row : elementsFeatures.select(".compare-products tbody tr")) {
        Elements rowCells = row.select("td");
        String gpsMap = rowCells.first().text();
        int i = 1;

        for (Element columnHeader : elementsFeatures.select(".compare-products thead tr th:gt(0)")) {
            System.out.format("%s -> %s: %s%n", columnHeader.text(), gpsMap, yesOrNo(rowCells.get(i)));
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static String yesOrNo(Element rowCell) {
    String ret = "no";
    if (rowCell.hasClass("checked")) {
        ret = "yes";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
7x1 -> Radar Overlay: yes
8x0/10x0 -> Radar Overlay: yes
4000/5000 -> Radar Overlay: yes
6000/7000 -> Radar Overlay: yes
7400/7600 -> Radar Overlay: yes
8000/8500 -> Radar Overlay: yes

7x1 -> Dual Range: no
8x0/10x0 -> Dual Range: no
4000/5000 -> Dual Range: yes
6000/7000 -> Dual Range: yes
7400/7600 -> Dual Range: yes
8000/8500 -> Dual Range: yes
...
```

**Details**

In the CSS query `.compare-products thead tr th:gt(0)`, `:gt(0)` means "*select all `th` except the first one*".